# Is there any way to not use import json in python?

Tags: python

I asked a question a little while ago and a kind soul helped me out, except I am not allowed to use import json, is there anyway that I can take that out and still get the code to work, I tried taking it out, but it didn't work. Please help! Thanks!

```
import json


suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  # creates an empty List
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)

print("Original List: ")
print(json.dumps(deck, indent=4))
print("")

sfuffled_deck = []

count = 0

while len(deck):
    if count%2 == 1:
        sfuffled_deck.append(deck.pop())
    else:
        sfuffled_deck.append(deck.pop(0))
    count+=1

print("Shuffled List: ")
print(json.dumps(sfuffled_deck, indent=4))
```

Comment: Can you use `pprint`?  how about `print("\n".join(deck))`?

Comment: You're just trying to print the data in pretty json format not load? Why use json in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to simulate what `json.dumps` would do for you. Fortunately, in this case it is rather simple:

```
print('[\n' + ',\n'.join([f'    "{x}"' for x in sfuffled_deck]) + '\n]')
```

Using f-strings you add four spaces and quotation marks, join all of that with commas and newline characters and add brackets around everything.

Answer (score 0):

What do wanna use json for?

If you want to display yout shuffled deck just use this :

`for card in shuffled_deck:
    print(card)`

Json allows you to structure data, save them and use them later. Is that what you want to do? Then you can write in a .txt file. Later, you open it, read it and get your data without using json.

Answer (score 0):

Modifications inline:

```py
# import json


suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  # creates an empty List
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)

print("Original List: ")
_ = [print("    " + card) for card in deck]
# print(json.dumps(deck, indent=4))
print("")

sfuffled_deck = []

count = 0

while len(deck):
    if count%2 == 1:
        sfuffled_deck.append(deck.pop())
    else:
        sfuffled_deck.append(deck.pop(0))
    count+=1

print("Shuffled List: ")
_ = [print("    " + card) for card in sfuffled_deck]
# print(json.dumps(sfuffled_deck, indent=4))
```

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to access the json module unless it is imported, so calls to json.dumps will not work without it. You will have to write your own code to do this logic yourself.

The first question you should ask yourself before completely reinventing the wheel on something that already exists is why? Generally it is bad practice to reimplement something that already exists in standard libraries if it is available to you. If this is a school project however, that might be the point.

Good luck!